# Is there any Iron solution that can reduce to Iron metal upon heating etc?

Tags: reduction-potential

The chemical should be water soluble and then should reduce to form Iron metal when heated up or upon adding some other chemical etc. The final product does not need to be solid metal, it can be in the form of powder (particles of nano micro etc) or just layer of deposits of Iron particles. Is there any chemical that is in the liquid form or water soluble, that can ultimately reduce to Iron metal?

Comment: The people who give negative votes should explain if the question is not up to standard, without leaving me wondering.

Comment: While I agree downvoting deserves explanation (unless it is already provided before), it does not necesserily mean the question is not up to standard. It just expresses subjective opinions, illustrated by mouse hints ( UP=This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear / DOWN=This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful ). // Be aware many SE sites  generally frown upon questions without explicit own trying to find the answer or to understand the topic. Questions being just the questions are frequently downvoted or voted to be closed.

Comment: Minus one. Also because a preliminary search would have answered your question or helped you writing a better one. Ex: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_nanoparticle

Comment: Since iron can displace hydrogen from water, leaving you with rust, you might try another solvent.

Comment: @Alchimista, "In the presence of oxygen and water, [iron nanoparticles] rapidly oxidize to form free iron ions. "

Comment: @DrMoishePippik well iron is iron,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, boiling many concentrated solutions containing a soluble Iron salts in an aluminum pot (which is the "or upon adding some other chemical etc.") will liberate Fe.

However, be mindful to limit the presence of air (else just common rust) and even an excess of water (see ["The Reaction Between Iron and Water in the Absence of Oxygen")](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1149/1.3071303/pdf).

Enjoy experimenting!

Comment: thanks a lot, so aluminum reacts with `Fe` solution to produce `aluminum oxide + Iron`, am I correct? So, I should be able to put aluminum pieces to a pot and `Fe` solution and still get the same result as using the aluminum pot isn't it. And about `excess of water`, to prepare the `Fe` solution, we need water to be added, so is it necessary to have no water in the solution? or I just have to limit it. I'm asking this because I'm thinking to use `FeCl3` and it needs water to become a solution. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @PrettyGirl this thread got more attention than what it deserve. In addition to the lack of search, you do not give context. Why? A trick to display? A homemade recipe for something? Etc. Equipment? Why not iron filings?

Comment: With dilute conditions, some so called hydrolysis reactions may occur, With significant air contract, oxidation reactions also (especially in the presence of Al+++ which forms a semi-valence complex, and note the presence of Al and Fe gives a galvanic cell aspect,). Perhaps run parallel reactions in limited air to a plate (significant surface area with interface) with both concentrated and dilute conditions and report back on observed results. Varying results may support why this experiment is a actually a good teaching exercise for both elementary and advanced students.

Comment: References: Article ‘Oxidative Stress Gated by Fenton and Haber Weiss Reactions and Its Association with Alzheimer’s Disease’ by Tushar Kanti Das, et al, published in Archives of Neuroscience, July 2014 2(3): e20078, DOI: 10.5812/archneurosci.20078. Key reaction formation of Aluminum Superoxide Semi reduced Radical Ion and Aluminum Superoxide Complex: [Al(H2O)4](3+) + O2•− <-> [Al(O2•−)(H2O)4](2+).

Comment: Reference: On the galvanic aspects (source of e- and with O2, the superoxide radical anion), see for example, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1876107020303230  . Quoting;  "The present paper constitutes a conjugate numerical and experimental study of a novel process patented as Galvano-Fenton, based on the association of galvanic corrosion and Fenton reaction. The study investigates the pathways of the in-situ formation and regeneration of iron species involved in electrochemical and chemical mechanisms of the Galvano-Fenton process...."

Comment: Reference: The hydrolysis of iron(III) chloride is the cationic reaction of the salt with water. Cationic hydrolysis is possible because the salt, iron(III) chloride, formed by a weak base (iron(III) hydroxide Fe(OH)₃) and a strong acid (hydrochloric acid HCl).  Link: https://melscience.com/US-en/articles/hydrolysis-reaction-iron-iii-chloride/

Comment: @AJKOER thanks a lot I'll go through one by one.